# Form letters with LaTeX

Tags: pdf, letters

I've got a simple LaTeX-Template for a letter (a bit TikZ and a single paragraph of text) and would like to generate a PDF-file (PDFLaTeX) with 100 letters using this template and names from a CSV-file.

Is there a package for that?